# Binding priority of forwarding reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, forwarding-reference

Can someone please help me to understand why the following code outputs `T&&` and NOT `const A&`:

```
class A{};

template< typename T >
void foo( T&& )
{
   std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl;
}


void foo( const A& )
{
   std::cout << "const A&" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  A a;
  foo( a );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[temp.deduct.call]/1 & 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#2) [emphasis mine]:

> **/1**
>
> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains
>   template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction
>   with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`)
>   as described below. ...
>
> **/3**
>
> ... A forwarding reference is **an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified
>   template parameter** that does not represent a template parameter of a
>   class template (during class template argument deduction
>   ([over.match.class.deduct])). **If `P` is a forwarding reference and the
>   argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in
>   place of `A` for type deduction**.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> ...
> template <class T> int f(T&& heisenreference);
> int i;
> int n1 = f(i);                  // calls f<int&>(int&)
> ...
> ```
>
> — end example]

Applied to your example, the `foo(a)` call will, for template argument deduction, resolve to `void foo<A&>(A&)`, which is an exact match for the cv-unqualified lvalue `a`. The non-template function `void foo(const A&)`, will, by [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6) (thanks @M.M for correcting which ranking rule that disambiguates these two), provide a worse conversion sequence than the template deducted one, and `void foo<A&>(A&)` will be have precedence in overload resolution.

> **/3.2**
>
> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> - ...
> - **/3.2.6** — `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level
>     cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2`
>     refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference
>     initialized by `S1` refers.

If you modify your example such that the non-template overload have the same top-level cv-qualifier(s) as the template deducted one (e.g. by removing the `const` cv-qualifier from the non-template function), it will result in the prior being chosen by overload resolution, .

```
class A {};

template< typename T >
void foo( T&& )
{
    std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl;
}

void foo( A& )
{
    std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo( a ); // "A&"
}
```

Comment: `A&` to `const A&` is an identity conversion, not a qualification conversion. The latter refers to adding const etc. at non-top levels

Comment: The actual ranking rule that disambiguates these two cases is C++14 [over.ics.rank]/3.1.6 "S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers
is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers."   (where the S1 is the specialization that was instantiated by overload resolution, i.e `template<> void foo<A&>(A&);`

Comment: @M.M Oh, my bad. Will jump into [over.ics.rank] and modify this answer accordingly, thanks! (Unless you'd like to add such an answer yourself, and I'll delete this one?)

Comment: It's just a minor quibble , you have 99% of the right answer